# Adding widgets to the list Kivy and KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

**I am trying to create an application, but I ran into a problem. I need to add items to the list using a for loop, but whenever I try to do this, I get an error message. I will also be glad to hear tips for improving the code.**

```
self.root.ids.List_setting.add_widget(
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

**Main.py:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.base import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
# Layout
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
#Widget KivyMD
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivymd.uix.imagelist import SmartTileWithLabel
from kivymd.uix.chip import MDChooseChip
from kivymd.uix.chip import MDChip
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.icon_definitions import md_icons
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextFieldRound
from kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation import MDBottomNavigation
from kivymd.uix.bottomnavigation import MDBottomNavigationBar
#widget Kivy
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class first_main_screen(Screen):
        Screen.name = 'Main'

class First_main_screen(Widget):
    pass

class main_activity(MDApp):
    Window.size = (400, 680)
    def build(self):
        global sm
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Purple"  # "Purple", "Red"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "500"  # "500"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file('screen_py/kv_screen/splash_screen.kv'))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file('kv_main/kv_main.kv'))
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(self.kv_main,5)
        self.fps_monitor_start()


    def kv_main(self, *args):
        sm.current = 'Main'
        self.root.ids.List_setting.add_widget(
            OneLineListItem(text=f'Items_13')
        )


if __name__=='__main__':
    main_activity().run()
```

**kv_main.kv:**

```
#:import images_path kivymd.images_path
first_main_screen:
    name:'Main'
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        size_hint:(None, None)
        height: root.height
        width: root.width
        MDBottomNavigation:
            panel_color: rgba(151, 172, 177)
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                panel_color: (151/255, 172/255, 177/255, 1/255)
                specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                text:'Главная'
                icon:'home'
                name: 'screen 1'
                RecycleView:
                    size_hint:(None, None)
                    height: root.height-57
                    width: root.width
                    MDGridLayout:
                        cols: 2
                        id:image_list
                        row_default_height: (self.width - self.cols*self.spacing[0]) / self.cols
                        row_force_default: True
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.minimum_height
                        spacing: dp(3)
                        SmartTileWithLabel:
                            text:'[size=26]Items 1 [/size]\n[size=14]Купить[/size]'
                            source:'image_main_kv/img.png'
                            height:('400dp')
                        SmartTileWithLabel:
                            text:'[size=26]Items 1 [/size]\n[size=14]Купить[/size]'
                            source:'image_main_kv/img.png'
                            height:('400dp')
                        SmartTileWithLabel:
                            text:'[size=26]Items 1 [/size]\n[size=14]Купить[/size]'
                            source:'image_main_kv/img.png'
                            height:('400dp')
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                panel_color: (151/255, 172/255, 177/255, 1/255)
                specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1,
                icon:'card-search'
                text:'Поиск'
                name: 'screen 2'
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation:'vertical'
                    pos_hint:{'top':1}
                    MDTextField:
                        text:'12312'
                    AnchorLayout:
                        anchor_x:'center'
                        anchor_y:'top'
                        MDChooseChip:
                            MDChip:
                                text: 'Check with icon'
                                icon: 'city'
                                check: True
            MDBottomNavigationItem:
                panel_color: (151/255, 172/255, 177/255, 1/255)
                specific_text_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
                text:'Настройки'
                icon:'account-settings'
                name: 'screen 3'
                RecycleView:
                    MDList:
                        id:List_setting
                        OneLineListItem:
                            text:'1231231'
```

**please explain how to fix this error or make the code effective.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because of the code:

```
    self.root.ids.List_setting.add_widget(
        OneLineListItem(text=f'Items_13')
    )
```

This code is trying to access the `ids` of the `root` widget of the `App`, but the `App` widget `root` is the `ScreenManager`, which has no `ids` defined. The `ids` in your `kv` file are defined in the `first_main_screen` widget. So, I think all you have to do is access the `ids` of the `first_main_screen`, like this:

```
    self.root.get_screen('Main').ids.List_setting.add_widget(
        OneLineListItem(text=f'Items_13')
    )
```

This uses the `get_screen()` method of the `ScreenManager`, that is the `root` of the `App`, to access the `first_main_screen` and then its `ids`.